# Updating field X with current timestamp when field Y gets updated in a table

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql on a project and I need to update a `password_last_updated` (timestamp) field every time the `password` field gets updated. Is there a way to detect updates on the `password` column using mysql and as soon as this update happens, the `password_last_updated` column will automatically get updated with the current timestamp?

Comment: I *think* you'd need to store passwords in a separate table for this to work

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that with a trigger which checks for a change in the password value, and sets `password_last_updated` to `current_timestamp` if it is different:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER  update_ts
BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.password != OLD.password THEN
    SET NEW.password_last_updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=632f5c7f9131deac73f295f02b5e0d00)

Comment: This seems like this should work although, I'm getting an error when running this command: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6`

Comment: @AnchovyLegend you probably need to set delimiters around the code. See my edit. dbfiddle generously deals with that for you...

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thats odd, never seen that. Why do we need to set delimiters?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend because otherwise MySQL thinks your statement ends when it sees the first `;` (in this case after the `SET` statement). Then the parser sees `END` (in the `END IF`) with no matching `BEGIN` so it says you have a syntax error because there's an empty string `''` before the `END`

Comment: is it possible to rewrite the above statement to possibly not require a delimiter? optionally, also removing the semi colons? I need to be able to pass a simplified string query as an argument to an ORM query function.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend unfortunately the semicolons are required for MySQL to figure out where the end of statements are. Some ORMs will allow you to not use the `DELIMITER` statements though. However I've come up with a bit of a hack utilising the fact that MySQL treats booleans as 1 or 0 in a numeric context; this only has one statement so no `;` in it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d9be8fe15bcdfecad609878cc88dbab